# Bootstrap's v4.5 checkbox cannot be aligned Horizontally or Vertically when next to an input

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, bootstrap-4

just like the title says: Bootstrap's checkbox cannot be aligned Horizontally or Vertically when next to an input.

Problem Rendering:

[image]

I have tried the following with no good results that code Snippet.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<div class="container mt-5">
<form>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                        Ex
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the class "align-items-center" to your form-group the checkbox will be aligned vertically.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<div class="container mt-5">
<form>
        <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-check orm-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                        Example checkbox
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are referring to the vertical alignment - that's because it's using Bootstrap's default values for margin. Add a custom margin-top value to #gridCheck1

Comment: Shouldn't there be any option within bootstrap for that ???

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Bootstrap is just a bunch of predefined styles and that's how they want it to look. If you want it to be different you will have to override their CSS.

Comment: I don't think that's the goal of bootstrap ... but thanks anyway for your opinion.